# Determining frequency of a plot by finding the coordinates of the peaks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to determine the frequency of this plot of position vs time:

[image: 1]

where the time and position datasets are lists of floats. I've tried using `scipy.signal.find_peaks` imported as `fp` but when I run this code:

```py
    peaks,_ = fp(pos)
    peak_times = []
    
    for i in range(len(peaks)):
        peak_times.append(t[i])
    
    peak_dists = [current-next for (current,next) in zip(peak_times,peak_times[1:])]
    approx_freq = sum(peak_dists)/len(peak_dists)
    
    return approx_freq
```

I get a type error: `typeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

What is going wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I spotted a few errors in your code. Here are the suggested corrections:

```py
peaks,_ = fp(pos)
peak_times = []

for i in peaks: # notice correction here! No range or len needed.
    peak_times.append(t[i])

peak_dists = [next-current for (current,next) in zip(peak_times,peak_times[1:])] # swapped next with current for positive result
approx_freq = 1/(sum(peak_dists)/len(peak_dists)) # take the inverse of what you did before
```

Good luck!